# Regular Expression : Finding the last 9 digits of a number and if the number is less than 9 digits than take the entire number

Tags: regex

I have been working on an regular expression which say consists of more than 9 digits ( 12345678910111213 )

With the help of regex \d{9}(?!\d)  i am able to find the last 9 digits of the number.

But when the entire number is less than 9 digits how do i take the entire number as pass it. is there any such regular expression.

Comment: The question is not related to Swift/Objective-C, please do not add the `nsregularexpression` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d{1,9}(?!\d)` will take as many as possible from the end, up to 9.

Comment: Awesome... \d{1,9}$   also this works fine for me... thanks a ton

Comment: The variant with the dollar sign requires the number to be at the end of the string, whereas your original attempt would find a 9-digit number anywhere within a string. If you only want numbers anchored to the end, the `$` notation is simpler and more explicit; but the `(?!\d)` variant is more general as it will pick up numbers anywhere. (Maybe increase the lower bound like `\d{5,9}(?!\d)` to only pick numbers with five digits or more if you want to avoid picking out really short numbers.)